# Помогите переделать код. Дана целочисленная матрица размера M × N. Найти номер первого из ее столбцов

Tags: python

Дана целочисленная матрица размера M × N. Найти номер первого из ее столбцов, содержащих максимальное количество одинаковых элементов.

Есть код на python, который находит строку:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [[1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 3, 3, 3, 4],
     [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
     [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
maxs = [Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][1] for x in a]
print(maxs.index(max(maxs))+1)
```

Как переделать код, чтобы находил столбец, а элементы матрицы вводились с клавиатуры?

Comment: `[list(x) for x in zip(*a)]` - https://ideone.com/0J6JUV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [62]: maxs = [Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][1] for x in zip(*a)]

In [63]: print(maxs.index(max(maxs))+1)
1
```

---

`zip(*a)` - вернет траспонированную матрицу

```
In [64]: list(zip(*a))
Out[64]:
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (2, 2, 3, 1, 1),
 (3, 2, 3, 1, 1),
 (3, 3, 3, 2, 0),
 (4, 4, 4, 3, 0)]
```

---

ввод матрицы:

```
In [73]: prompt = "Введите элементы матрицы, разделенные пробелом. Используйте ';' для разделителя строк: "

In [74]: a = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in input(prompt).split(";")]
Введите элементы матрицы, разделенные пробелом. Используйте ';' для разделителя строк: 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;10 11 12

In [75]: a
Out[75]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: О, прикольно)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, все самое интересное код из вопроса уже содержит ;)

Comment: Ещё считывание интересно, если число строк неизвестно. Можно как-то красиво записать?  Пожалуй, отдельным вопросом задам)

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил ввод матрицы в ответ...)

Comment: Вот, задал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1026165/178988