# Как красиво прочитать двумерную матрицу?

Tags: python, input, матрицы

Собственно, могу прочитать вот так: https://ideone.com/SCoCuG

```
def read_lines():
  try:
    line = input()
    while line:
      yield line
      line = input()
  except EOFError:
    pass

def read_matrix():
  return [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in read_lines()]

a = read_matrix()
print(a)

b = read_matrix()
print(b)
```

Но мне кажется, что это как-то не по-питоньи, и должен быть способ красивее?

Входные данные: числа, разделённые пробелами по строке матрицы в каждой строке ввода, ввод завершается пустой строкой или концом файла.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6

7 8
9 0
1 2
```

Comment: сначала подумал про считать не как про read а как про count

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а до меня смысл твоего комментария только с третьего прочтения дошёл))) Поправил заголовок. Надеюсь теперь не получилось "прочитать вслух"? xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

мой вариант https://ideone.com/xwsY1A

```
import sys
from itertools import takewhile


def read_matrix():
    return [[int(x) for x in l.split()] for l in takewhile(str.strip, sys.stdin)]


a = read_matrix()
print(a)

b = read_matrix()
print(b)
```

Comment: Ну в принципе вариант) С ним никаких косяков не будет при дальнейшем считывании?

Comment: @Qwertiy да не должно быть, работает как и ваша, следующий input() будет блокирующим в консоле или кинет EOFError если файл подсунули и он кончился

Comment: Я просто про смешение разных способов чтения и буферизацию подумал. Но раз всё хорошо, то отлично :)

Comment: Вместо лямбды можно просто использовать функцию `str.strip`: `takewhile(str.strip, sys.stdin)`.